# A matrix (vector) in armadillo gains new decimal places after loading it from a file

Tags: python, c++, armadillo

I want to transfer the sourcecode from python to c++ (#include < armadillo >).
I have a vector (matrix) saved to "my_vec.txt" with the dimension 1x200 :

```
-0.082833
0.151422
-0.088526
...
...
0.115863
0.131043
0.041844
```

I want to calculate the dot-product of two my_vec's in python (this is just an example for testing).

```
result = my_vec.dot(my_vec)
print (str.format("{0:.10f}", result))
```

gives me **6.1402435303** as a result

When I try to do the same operation in c++ with armadillo:

```
float result;
result = dot(my_vec, my_vec);
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << result;
```

I get **6.140244007**.

So I looked at my float-vector *my_vec* in armadillo after loading the values from the text file. This is how it looks like:

```
 -8.283299952745e-002
  1.514219939709e-001
 -8.852600306273e-002
 ...
 ...
 1.158630028367e-001
 1.310430020094e-001
 4.184399917722e-002
```

So many decimal places were added (that are not existing in my_vec.txt). Of course, this difference has influence on the further computation. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you used less precision in your C++ code. C++ `float` usually corresponds to NumPy `float32`; if you want precision equivalent to a NumPy `float64`, that's generally C++ `double`.

Comment: Thank you for response. The way I load my matrix in python is: 
my_vec = np.loadtxt(my_vec_file,     dtype=np.float32).
It is float32. So I use fvec (for floats) in armadillo instead of vec (for doubles), but I still get different values after the computation of dot-product.
Where exactly should I change the precision. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I save my matrix back to txt-file (in python), It has the following precision:
-8.283299952745437622e-02

Comment: @KTBFFH: If you're using 32-bit floats deliberately, then this degree of difference is expected. 32-bit floats only hold about 6 decimal digits of precision; you're just forcing the program to display digits that are essentially noise.

Comment: I have to transfer the python code in c++, so unfortunately if it calls np.float32, I have to accept that und try to reproduce the same result in c++.
Let me sum up (first value of the vector).
txt: -0.082833
after loadtxt (dtype=np.float32) in python: -8.283299952745437622e-02
after load(.txt) in c++ armadillo: -8.283299952745e-002
The essentially noise of the float value is the same for the both programs. But python displays more digits that has influence for some futher operations (like multiplication).How I get the same precision for my armadillo matrix like in python? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KTBFFH: The results of loading are most likely identical - Python is just showing you more digits. If you want exactly identical output for all the calculations after that, though, you'd need specialized libraries deliberately oriented around exact reproducibility. Almost everyone sacrifices reproducibility for speed.

Comment: Maybe it is also possible with armadillo, but it is something for a new topic. Thank you for your help!